# Lagrange vs Newton Interpolation Error Term

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I have reached the same error term for both Lagrange and Newton's method. Since the interpolation polynomial is unique can I claim that none of the methods is better than the other in terms of accuracy?